# How to validate every record in the store by making an ajax call and checking its response Extjs

Tags: ajax, extjs, store, extjs5, extjs6

I have a panel with a header form and a detail form detail form consist of a grid and a form.
If the user clicks on save button which is in the header I have to take the value JDE present in the header as one parameter and check the REFNo present in each record present in the detailStore and make an ajax call.

If the data returned from the response is null I have to disable the save call.
Sample ajax call I am using in my code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: webContext + '/services/adjustment/accountsreceivableledger',
    timeout: 120000,
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        addressNumber: jde,
        documentNumber: r.data.customerInvoiceDebitNo
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var returnedValue = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

        if (returnedValue.data != null && returnedValue.data.length === 0) {
            me.lookupReference('submit').disable();

            Ext.Msg.alert('Submitting Error on Detail Reference number');
            refValid = false;
            me.getView().up('panel').ownerCt.unmask();
        } else {
            refValid = true;
        }
        return refValid;
    }
});
```

[Sample fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2bf1&view/editor)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: For Example :
In the header i have JDE as 5 
and in the detail for suppose I have three records 
1) id: 1, Refno: 966, Name: distinctio
2) id:2, Refno: 510, Name: aut
3)id:3, Refno: 162, Name: 

so before saving the ajax call should be made for all the 3 records 
1st call :jde: 5, refno: 966
2nd call : jde 5, refno : 510
3rd call jde 5, refno : 162

i need to check all the return responses and if the response data is not null or Empty then only submit the call.

Comment: I TRIED CALLING THIS FUNCTION ON SAVE

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bhu

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just concatenate all the ref numbers and pass to the server in one go?

```
var myRefParameter;

YourStore.each(function(r) {
    if (myRefParameter!='') 
        myRefParameter +='|';
    myRefParameter += r.get('RefField');
});

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: webContext + '/services/adjustment/accountsreceivableledger',
    timeout: 120000,
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        addressNumber: jde,
        documentNumber: myRefParameter //Pass it here
    },
...........
```

Just split the Ref. Numbers on the server and do all the necessary validations.

Comment: Thanks Barros I tried this way but it is just making one call with one reference number

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement,

> I need to check all the return responses and if the response data is not null or Empty then only submit the call

For this you need to create a common `ajax` call function and call this function on `save` button for every `record` as present on store. You have to maintain one array for `customerInvoiceDebitNo` and one `ajaxcount` to check all response. You need to put bellow code on your `save` button click event.

You can modify below code basis of your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
var customerInvoiceDebitNo = '',
    allCustomerInvoiceDebitNo = [],
    ajaxCount = 0;

detailStore.each(function(r) {
    customerInvoiceDebitNo = r.get('customerInvoiceDebitNo');
    if (customerInvoiceDebitNo !== 0 && detlview.getViewModel().get('currentHeader').data.sourceDocuments[0].documentNumber !== customerInvoiceDebitNo) {
        //call ajax request for per record  
        doApiCall({
            addressNumber: jde,
            documentNumber: customerInvoiceDebitNo
        });
        //Push customer invoice debit no in Array for checking response in Ajax request success.
        allCustomerInvoiceDebitNo.push(customerInvoiceDebitNo);
        //For checking number of ajax call.  
        ajaxCount++;
    }

});

//This function will make ajax call for per record
function doApiCall(data) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: webContext + '/services/adjustment/accountsreceivableledger',
        timeout: 120000,
        method: 'GET',
        params: data,
        customerInvoiceDebitNo: data.customerInvoiceDebitNo,
        success: function(response) {
            ajaxCount--;
            //When All ajax request response will get then unmask on view
            if (ajaxCount == 0) {
                me.getView().up('panel').ownerCt.unmask();
            }
            var returnedValue = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            if (returnedValue.data != null && returnedValue.data.length === 0) {
                //Remove this current customerInvoiceDebitNo from array if response is not null. 
                Ext.Array.remove(allCustomerInvoiceDebitNo, this.customerInvoiceDebitNo);
                //Initially submit button will be disable   
                //If all ajax request response is not null then array will be empty then we can make sumit button enable.
                if (Ext.isEmpty(allCustomerInvoiceDebitNo)) {

                }
            }

        }
    });
}
//Initially submit button will be disable   
//This function will enable submit button when all request reponse will not null or empty.
function doEnableSumbitButton() {
    me.lookupReference('submit').setDisabled(false);
}
```

I hope this will guide or help you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: thanks Njdhv it works good except  Ext.Ajax call is asynchronous and the function doApiCall() is not waiting for the success callback to execute which is why refValid value is not getting updated and unable to return from the loop

Comment: You are doing `ajax` call inside of loop method and `ajax` response time depend on sever it will take 5s or 10s or may be more. you want to check every ajax `request` response. In that case you need to maintain a `variable` or whatever you want. If you one `request response`   is container null then you can put this `variable` as `false`.

Comment: Or another way you can pas all `customerInvoiceDebitNo` with `jde` like this `{addressNumber: jde,documentNumber: '1,2,3,11,5'}` but in case `serverside` you need to create api that will check all `customerInvoiceDebitNo` with passed `jde` value.

Comment: I am trying to use promises here but still even if the refValid is true unable to return to the submit call please see the fidddle [link]https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bn5

Comment: can you please explain this You are doing ajax call inside of loop method and ajax response time depend on sever it will take 5s or 10s or may be more. you want to check every ajax request response. In that case you need to maintain a variable or whatever you want. If you one request response is container null then you can put this variable as false  got struck

Comment: @Sweety for this you need to work `serverside` as well. Because your are passing all `customerInvoiceDebitNo` like this `{addressNumber: jde,documentNumber: '1,2,3,11,5'}`.